# Do I need a Schengen transit visa as a US Green Card holder?

Tags: visas, schengen

I am travelling from  Washington DC to Copenhagen ( layover 4 hours ) then to Newcastle UK. Do I need a schengen visa? I have a green card and 5 year UK visa and am a citizen of India

Answer (score 2):

As stated in [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&SECTION=VI&COUNTRY=dk&SUBSECTION=TW&ExpertMode22=&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX), the database used by airlines:

> Visa required, **except** for holders of onward tickets transiting on the
>     same calendar day if arriving at and departing from
>     Copenhagen Kastrup (CPH).

So no, you do **not** need a visa.